# I think im using an rvm installed version of ruby, but bash does not recognize the rvm command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rvm

I dont think I ever installed rvm on my local machine... I installed it in an IDE     (EDIT: the IDE is Nitrous.io) as per the request of a tutorial I was doing with (Coder Manual). 
When I type `ruby -v` in bash, I get `ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]` but I just installed the latest version of ruby with homebrew, so I know there is a later version than 2.0.0 on my system...

When I try to run `rvm uninstall 2.0.0` I get `-bash: rvm: command not found`

I am extremely new to ALL of this... and frankly have no clue what i'm doing. but I would like to just have the regular Ruby installed. until at least I DO know what im doing.... can anybody help me figure out what is going on??

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to your `bashrc` or `bash_profile`, whichever you use:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Use in terminal:

```
source <UPDATED FILE>
```

to restart your terminal session

Comment: use `source <UPDATED FILE>` afterwards, or restart your terminal session ;)

Comment: I dont know which one I use.... Im on Mac OSX Yosemite so I think I use `.bash_profile`??
I cant find either of those anyhow...
When I do find them, I just add those lined anywhere in the file?
what will that do?

Comment: both of `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` are located in your home directory. `/Users/<your_username>`, if you are using mac

Comment: Dont see either one of them.

Comment: there are hidden files. try `cat ~/.bashrc` in terminal, you shall see the contents